# Method that displays a GUI Window

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PictureViewer {

    final static int MIN_NUMBER = 1;
    final static int MAX_NUMBER = 8;
    static int image_number = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        showMenu();
    }

    public static int forward(int current_number) {
        if (current_number < MAX_NUMBER) {
        current_number++;
    } else {
        current_number = MAX_NUMBER;
    }
    return current_number;

    public static int backward(int current_number) {
        if (current_number > MIN_NUMBER) {
            current_number--;
        }
        return current_number;
    }

    public static String createFileName(int current_number) {
        return ("Picture " + current_number + ".jpg");

    }

    public static String createRandomName() {
        return ("Picture " + (int) (Math.random() * 8 + 1) + ".jpg");
    }

    public static void showMenu() {

        PictureViewer theobject = new PictureViewer();

        int current_number = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Choose static forward(1), static backward(2),"
                + " createFileName(3), createRandomName(4)");
            int user = input.nextInt();

            switch (user) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("static forward");
                    current_number = forward(current_number);
                    theobject.forward();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("static backward");
                    current_number = backward(current_number);
                    theobject.backward();
                    break;
                case 3:
                System.out.println("createFileName");
                createFileName(current_number);
                theobject.showWindow(createFileName(current_number));
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("createRandomName");
                createRandomName();
                theobject.showWindow(createRandomName());

            }
            if (image_number != 1);
            System.out.println(image_number);
        }
    }

    public void forward() {

        if (image_number < MAX_NUMBER) {
            image_number++;
        } else {
            image_number = MAX_NUMBER;
        }
    }

    public void backward() {

        if (image_number > MIN_NUMBER) {
            image_number--;
        }
    }

    public void showWindow(String filename) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI Window");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

What I'm supposed to do:

Write a new function to create and display a GUI window (which I did by doing the showWindow method but I'm not sure how to code the rest of it).

In your switch statement, where you call the methods createFileName() and createRandomName(), add calls to object.showWindow() and pass it the file name the methods return (I added object.showWindow() to those particular methods but I'm getting errors). Test your program, you should be able to go forward and backward with proper behavior when MIN_NUMBER and MAX_NUMBER are reached. When the window is displayed the correct file name should be shown at the top of the frame.

Areas of interest:

Here

```
case 3:
    System.out.println("createFileName");
    createFileName(current_number);
    theobject.showWindow();
    break;
case 4:
    System.out.println("createRandomName");
    createRandomName();
    theobject.showWindow();
```

and here

```
public void showWindow(String filename) {

}
```

Comment: by GUI Window, did you mean [JFrames](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) or perhaps [JPanels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html)?

Comment: JFrames most likely. Here's the exact instructions: public void showWindow(String filename) {
// NOT static, must use object to execute
// Create, size and show a GUI window frame, you may need to
// click on taskbar to see window.
// Display the filename in the title of the window frame, otherwise the // window will be blank (for now)
}

Comment: Please try and [indent](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/top-15-best-practices-for-writing-super-readable-code--net-8118) your code to make it more readable. The tutorial I linked to previously is a good place to start.

Comment: I fixed it up a bit. Does that help?

Comment: Why'd you remove the indentation? It looks less readable now :|

Comment: Alright I indented it. It should look neater.

Comment: There you go. Looks better now. I provided an answer so can you provide some feedback if it works?

Comment: While editing this code for indentation, I think you introduced some compile errors. I went ahead and [fixed](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9938077) them as they are unrelated to your previous problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, the compile errors in your program. I copied and pasted your code to my IDE and in the `object.showWindow()` lines I get compile errors it says:

> method showWindow in class PictureViewer cannot be applied to given types;
>
> required: String
>
> found: no arguments
>
> reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

To a Java beginner, this may seem cryptic, however it just tells you that the method you are calling, in this case the `showWindow()` method, is requiring you to pass a String but you are not passing anyting that's why it throws an error. Also, in your question you said

> call the methods createFileName() and createRandomName(), add calls to object.showWindow() and pass it the file name the methods return

It is very clear now what to do to remove the compile errors. You need to *pass* the methods `createFileName()` and `createRandomName()`. After doing so, it will look like this:

```
case 3:
    System.out.println("createFileName");
    theobject.showWindow(createFileName(current_number));
    break;
case 4:
    System.out.println("createRandomName");
    theobject.showWindow(createRandomName());
```

Next is the *creating and displaying the GUI Window*. I will show you how to do this in pseudocode first so you will learn how to do it yourself.

First, add a global variable that we will use to refer to the window. Then, in the `showWindow()` method:

```
public void showWindow(String filename) {
    if window is null
        initialize new window
        set the window title using filename
        show window
    else
        set the window title using filename
}
```

Comment: I was able to fix the errors in the switch statements.  I added the fixes in my original post. Thanks! Now I just have to figure out the showWindow method.

Comment: @Shiiiro you were able to fix them but what you did was wrong :|. You must've misunderstood my answer. The methods themselves can be passed because they are equivalent to what they return. As for the `showWindow()`, what output are you getting now?

Comment: So I think I'm supposed to write "JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI Window");" but I'm not sure how to make the filename the same as the ones in case 3 and case 4 of my code.

Comment: @Shiiiro there is a [setTitle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setTitle(java.lang.String)) method you can use for JFrame

Comment: So is what the methods return such as  return ("Picture " + current_number + ".jpg"); and return ("Picture " + (int) (Math.random() * 8 + 1) + ".jpg"); not what I'm supposed to put within the parenthesis of the theobject.showWindow(); in case 3 and case 4?

Comment: Actually, you can put them. It works right? Although it *works*, it is *incorrect* and your professor will mark it wrong. Explaining *why it is wrong* will take a very long post, but you can ask your professor about the reason why it's wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I'd rather get it correct than code something wrong despite it working.

Comment: It does but I'm still not sure how to make it so that the window's name is the same as case 3 and case 4's.

Comment: Then I believe that this question is already answered. I also think that all the resources/answers/guides that you need to solve your problem and your homework is all in this post. No need to ask more questions. All you need is to believe in your own problem solving skills. Programming is all about problem solving after all.

Comment: All right. Thank you for all your help. I'll figure this out on my own.